# What does $p(X) \mapsto p(X+1)$ mean as a linear mapping.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, polynomials, vector-spaces

I have the linear map: $p(X) \mapsto p(X+1)$ with the standard basis $B = \{1,X,X^2\}$. 
Is it right that, for example, $P(1) = P(1+1) = P(2)$ and $P(X) = P(X+1)$, so that i have the vectors $(2,0,0)$ and $(1,1,0)$, respectively (with respect to the basis $B$).

I understand that its a stupid question but i'm a bit confused (because my answers say otherwise)..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is how I understand your question.

> In the space 
>   $\mathbb{P}^2[x] =
>      \left\{ \left. ax^2 + bx + c \right| a,b,c \in \mathbb{R} \right\}$
>   of all 2nd-degree polynomials with real coefficients, and the standard basis $B = \left\{1,x,x^2\right\}$ of $\mathbb{P}^2[x]$, consider a map $f:\mathbb{P}^2[x] \to \mathbb{P}^2[x]$ which maps $p(x) \mapsto p(x+1)$. You would like to understand the images of $1$ and $x$ under $f$, which you are expressing in vector form.

Here is what is happening. Let $p(x) \equiv 1$ and $q(x) = x$ and $r(x) = x^2$. Then you have

- $f(p(x)) = p(x+1) = 1$ since $p(\cdot) = 1$ for any input whatsoever, hence $p(x)=p(x+1)=1$;
- $f(q(x)) = q(x+1) = x+1$;
- $f(r(x)) = r(x+1) = (x+1)^2 = x^2 + 2x + 1$.

In the vector notation you seem to be using, a polynomial $ax^2+bx+c$ is represented as a vector of coefficients $(c,b,a)^T$. In that notation, $f$ maps these examples as follows:
$$
p = \begin{pmatrix} 1 \\ 0 \\ 0 \end{pmatrix} \mapsto 
\begin{pmatrix} 1 \\ 0 \\ 0 \end{pmatrix} = f(p),
q = \begin{pmatrix} 0 \\ 1 \\ 0 \end{pmatrix} \mapsto 
\begin{pmatrix} 1 \\ 1 \\ 0 \end{pmatrix} = f(q),
r = \begin{pmatrix} 0 \\ 0 \\ 1 \end{pmatrix} \mapsto 
\begin{pmatrix} 1 \\ 2 \\ 1 \end{pmatrix} = f(r)
$$

In matrix notation, you can write
$$
\begin{pmatrix}
 1 & 0 & 0\\
 0 & 1 & 0\\
 0 & 0 & 1
\end{pmatrix}
\mapsto 
\begin{pmatrix}
 1 & 1 & 1\\
 0 & 1 & 2\\
 0 & 0 & 1
\end{pmatrix},
$$
which is indeed a linear map.

Hope that clears things up.

Comment: I'm almost ashamed that i get a so precise answer for my rather "undetailed" question. Thanks a lot! I understand it now.